# Save div contents as they are displayed (not the coding behind it all)

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

Using this js I am able to save the contents of a div as a file..

```
function download(){
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "test.csv";
    a.href = "data:text/csv charset=utf-8," + document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML;
    a.click();
```

then on the page..

```
</div><button onClick="download()">Download</button>
```

My issue is that I wish to save the contents of the div exactly as they are rendered on the page (shown in the browser) but using this current method it saves with the markup included aswell.

I have tried (and failed with)..

1) `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText`
2) `document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent;`
3) `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Is there a more simple way to save what is seen not what is coded to make it that way??

**EDIT TO ADD MORE INFO**

The div contents are just needed to be saved as plain txt, exactly the same as they would be if I copy/paste the div contents into notepad.

This is an example of the div contents..

```
listing_id,title,description,price,quantity,taxonomy_id,shipping_template_id,shop_section_id,state,when_made,who_made,materials,tags,processing_min,processing_max,is_supply,is_customizable,non_taxable,sku,variations,images
,"TITLE","DESCRIPTION",2.49,99,1319,58517133942,,active,made_to_order,i_did,,"TAGS",1,2,0,0,0,SKU," [{
""Sticker Color"": ""Red"",
""Sticker Size"": ""SML 169x80mm"",
""price"": 2.30
}, {
""Sticker Color"": ""Red"",
""Sticker Size"": ""STD 190x90mm"",
""price"": 2.49
}, {
""Sticker Color"": ""Red"",
""Sticker Size"": ""MED 210x99mm"",
""price"": 3.49
}, {
""Sticker Color"": ""Red"",
""Sticker Size"": ""LRG 295x140mm"",
""price"": 5.49
}]","http://MyURL.com/a-black.png,http://MyURL.com/b-red.png,http://MyURL.com/c-green.png,http://MyURL.com/d-purple.png,http://MyURL.com/e-blue.png,http://MyURL.com/f-white.png,http://MyURL.com/g-yellow.png,http://MyURL.com/h-orange.png,http://MyURL.com/i-light-blue.png,http://MyURL.com/j-gold.png,http://MyURL.com/k-no-bg.png,http://MyURL.com/l-colour-options.png,"
```

lots of parts of the above is generated with (based on user inputs)...

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = document.getElementById("y").innerHTML;
```

```
<span id="x"></span>
```

The problem is at the moment when I save it the saved version includes the `<span id="x"></span>` info as well as the text that outputs.

**MORE INFO**

I seem to be a step closer with..

```
var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("x"));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
var p = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "test.csv";
    a.href = "data:text/csv charset=utf-8," + range;
    a.click();
```

which in a jsfiddle appears to work as I wanted however when tested with more div contents (5x the text) the downloaded file gets cut off after just a few (5) lines. Any idea why?

Comment: Try to use Jqueries Text method.
$('#mydiv').text()

Comment: I would like to stick to pure js if possible.

Comment: Some browsers support innerText (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Comment: I tried innerText as mentioned in my op but this doesn't keep the contents the same either.

Comment: Post example of your div with all html it contains

Comment: I've edited my op to include more info, an example has now been added.

Comment: If extra text is just html elements, I think regex can do the job https://jsfiddle.net/L5s4gzjf/1/

Comment: This does not work, if you open the file your jsfiddle creates in notepad you will see the <span id="x"></span> is still on the end.

Comment: I've also tried with var regex = (/<[^>]*>/g, ' '); after searching using regex to remove html tags but still no luck the downloaded file still contains <span id="x"></span>

Comment: Having tried many things today I am still no further forward with a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download it exactly like it is rendered by browser, you need to convert HTML to image and then download the image.

You should try to use some existing library, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image

Comment: The div contains a dynamically generated CSV (based on user inputs previously on the page). if I copy/paste the div contents into notepad and save as CSV it all works perfectly when I later need to use the CSV so an image would be of no use for me.